# Windows 8 Installation on VirtualBox Driver Issue

Tags: windows-8, virtualbox, drivers

I am trying to install Windows 8 from an ISO on VirtualBox 4.2.13 (on Win 7).

After I click install, It starts processing before showing a message that it can't find some drivers.[image: Win8 Install Problem]

What drivers could be missing? Is the ISO incomplete?
This is a brand new VM with a Dynamically sized disk.

Comment: the latest VirtualBox version is 4.3.18. Update to the latest version and try again.

Comment: VB is saying it is upto date, but I will have a look

Comment: Just tried .18, same error

Comment: check the has of the Windows 7 ISO (http://code.kliu.org/hashcheck/) and compare it to the hash values that Microsoft provides.